# Ant build takes longer than eclipse build (Through ADT)

Tags: android, performance, ant, build

I use eclipse sometimes to build my android project(Using ADT 19). If i have modified only 1 files then the build happens very quickly from Eclipse (Using Ctr+B). But if i use the ant script (I use "ant debug") command to build it takes longer. I believe this is because, it is building all the files again.

Basically ant build takes the same time as that of a clean build. Is there some way to speed up the ant build ?

Here is the output of ant script...

```
    set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-setup:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] Gathering info for Astro...
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 19
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.3.3
    [setup] API level: 10
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------

-build-setup:

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Sample\bin\classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
```

Comment: You may want to post some of your ant file. Normally, ant shouldn't behave like that.

Comment: I have not modified the build.xml at all. I just used android update command to generate one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it myself. My IDE was set to clean the project and build it every time. It had ant clean debug. Removed "clean" and it works...